# How to use a managed Tauri state variable inside a spawned tauri async runtime thread?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, mutex, tauri

I am trying to build this app where I have a command that starts a thread that publishes many messages to RabbitMQ, and then emits an event once it is done publishing.
I have a managed `ConnectionMutex` struct using `tauri`'s state API, and I am also getting the window handle to emit events.
the code looks like the following:

```rust
use tauri::async_runtime::Mutex;
pub struct ConnectionMutex(pub Mutex<Option<RabbitMqConnection>>);


#[tauri::command]
pub async fn publish_message(
    connection_mutex: tauri::State<'_, ConnectionMutex>,
    window: tauri::Window,
) -> Result<(), String> { 
    tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
        let lock = connection_mutex
            .0
            .try_lock()
            .map_err(|_| String::from("cannot change connection while it is being used"))
            .unwrap();
        let conn = lock.as_ref().ok_or("no rabbitmq connection").unwrap();

        let _ = rabbitmq::publishing::publish(
            &conn.target,
            &conn.channel,
            window,
        )
        .await;
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

I get a compiler error saying: `borrowed data escapes outside of function`. this error makes sense to me, I understand why this would not be safe because the rust borrow checker could no longer track the borrowed variable and will be unable to free it at the correct time.
However, I have no idea the correct way to achieve this kind of stuff in Rust.

I also tried setting the lifetime of the `State` variable to static,like this:

```rust
#[tauri::command]
pub async fn publish_message(
    connection_mutex: tauri::State<'static, ConnectionMutex>,
    window: tauri::Window,
) -> Result<(), String>
```

but I get a different error: `__tauri_message__ does not live long enough`

Comment: Which RabbitMQ library are you using by the way?

Comment: I used `amqprs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to wrap the `Mutex` in `Arc` so that you can safely share references to the underlying `Mutex` across `async` tasks. (See also [the example in the docs](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/async_runtime/struct.Mutex.html#examples)).

So your `ConnectionMutex` could look like:

```rust
pub struct ConnectionMutex(pub Arc<Mutex<Option<RabbitMqConnection>>>);
```

Then, when you want to pass the connection when you spawn an `async` task, you first `clone()` the `ConnectionMutex` to give the task it's own copy of the reference.

```rust
#[tauri::command]
pub async fn publish_message(
    connection_mutex: tauri::State<'_, ConnectionMutex>,
    window: tauri::Window,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    let connection = Arc::clone(&connection_mutex.0);

    tauri::async_runtime::spawn(async move {
        let lock = connection
            .try_lock()
            .map_err(|_| String::from("cannot change connection while it is being used"))
            .unwrap();

        let conn = lock.as_ref().ok_or("no rabbitmq connection").unwrap();

        let _ = rabbitmq::publishing::publish(
            &conn.target,
            &conn.channel,
            window,
        )
        .await;
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works, with a slight change for anyone reading this in the future. note that the `State<T>` is not an `Arc` and not a `Mutex`, so cloning this variable did not work for me. but if you access the underlying `Arc` and clone it it does work. ` let safe_ref = Arc::clone(&connection_mutex.0);`.

Comment: @ZivCaspi Cool! I'll update the answer with that then